# Javascript: Using a string as a variable name in the code

Tags: javascript, string, variables

I am writing JavaScript code that has a loop. There is statement in the loop:
foo = foo +1. ;
I want the code to treat foo as different variable each time the loop runs. For example:

```
first loop -->  env.x = env.x + 2.0 ;
second loop --> env.y = env.y+ 2.0 ;
third loop -->  env.z = env.z + 2.0 ;
```

I have looked at other solutions posted like using eval() and window() functions but still can't figure how to do this.

UPDATE: To help better understand my problem I am posting a part of the code:

```
if (profile.xChaos.toFixed(0) > 500.) {
                               
if (profile.param1 == 2.0) { 
profile.param1 = 0.25 ;
profile.param2 += 0.25 ;
console.log('Reset. param1 =' + profile.param1 + '; param2 increment = '+profile.param2);
}
else{profile.param1 += 0.25 ;}
profile.gui.updateDisplay({verbose : false}) ;
}
```

I would like to implement this in such a way that the code effectively executes these lines as:

```
if (profile.xChaos.toFixed(0) > 500.) {
                               
if (profile.x == 2.0) { 
profile.x = 0.25 ;
profile.y += 0.25 ;
console.log('Reset. x =' + profile.x + '; y increment = '+profile.y);
}
else{profile.x += 0.25 ;}
profile.gui.updateDisplay({verbose : false}) ;
}
```

where x,y can be chosen from a set of variables {profile.a, profile.b, profile.c . . .}. I hope this makes it clearer. Thanks.

Comment: Use an object instead, don't use variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of property names, then iterate over that:

```
const keys = ['x', 'y', 'z'];
for (const key of keys) {
  env[key] = env[key] + 2.0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. However, I have a complicated piece of code inside the "for". I am looking for a solution where I can use a small variable name like var1 and var2 an then just set var1 and var2 that act as env.x or env.y or env.z as required.

Comment: Generally, when you have a question, you should post your *actual code*, not psuedo-code - that way you can receive useful answers. Can you post your actual code?

Comment: To be clear, post some actual code, but usually a minimal reproduction of the issue you have.

Comment: I used the method given by @CertainPerformance and it worked flawlessly. Marking the problem as solved. Thank you all.